# OR condition in Bison statement structure

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I have the following Bison file  -

```
%union
{
    int integer_value;
    double double_value;
    char* string_value;
}

%token <integer_value> INTEGER
%token <string_value> VAR
%token <string_value> INTEGER_DECLARATION
%token <double_value> DOUBLE
%token <string_value> DOUBLE_DECLARATION


%%

program:
        program statement '\n'
        |
        ;

statement:
        | INTEGER_DECLARATION VAR '=' INTEGER {//implementation} 

        | INTEGER_DECLARATION VAR '='  DOUBLE {//implementation as above}                            

%%
```

Since the implementation in both `INTEGER_DECLARATION VAR '=' INTEGER` and `INTEGER_DECLARATION VAR '='  DOUBLE` is the same  , is it possible to make `OR` condition bw `INTEGER` and `DOUBLE` in the statement structure ?

I tried `INTEGER_DECLARATION VAR '=' INTEGER|DOUBLE` but it prompted  `warning: rule useless in parser due to conflicts: statement: DOUBLE` and indeed the refer to `DOUBLE` was ignored  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main code snippet that you have posted is about as concise as you can be. `statement: INTEGER_DECLARATION VAR '=' INTEGER|DOUBLE` is trying to say that a `statement` can consist of nothing but a `DOUBLE`.

You could write this:

```
program:
      program statement '\n'
    |
    ;

statement:
      decl_part INTEGER {//implementation uses info in $1} 
    | decl_part DOUBLE {//implementation as above}                            
    ;

decl_part:
      INTEGER_DECLARATION VAR '=' {//partial implementation passes some info via $$}
    ;
```

but it's debatable whether that improves on what you have already.

Or you could write:

```
program:
      program statement '\n'
    |
    ;

statement:
      INTEGER_DECLARATION VAR '=' number
    ;

number:
      INTEGER
    | DOUBLE
    ;
```

This technique has advantages when you later want to extend your language, for instance, to support hexadecimal constants.

One other note: I don't think you want the first alternation symbol in your productions for `statement`.  The way you have it, both `program` and `statement` can be epsilon (empty), and I believe that this will lead to parser conflicts.